# Why does my C# regular expression that asks for 7 characters accept 8 characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# regular expression that I'd like to match 7 characters:

```
string digits4 = "\\d{4}";
string allowable3 = "[a-zA-z0-9 $%&#?+=!]{3}";
Regex regex1 = new Regex(digits4 + allowable3);
```

`allowable3` is meant to match three letters, numbers, or any of the subsequent characters. However, the following returns true:

```
regex1.IsMatch("1234abc^")
```

This confuses me for two reasons:

1. The matched pattern has 8 characters.
2. The `allowable3` doesn't include "^".
   I must have some additional, unexpected wild card matching going on within my "[positive character group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#PositiveGroup)" (the part within the square brackets), but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Use anchors ^ and $ round the pattern. IsMatch searches for partial matches when the pattern is not anchored.

Comment: You need anchors `^` and `$` to match complete string and not just check if the string's some part satisfies the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use anchors ^ and $ round the pattern to require a full string match. IsMatch searches for partial matches when the pattern is not anchored.

Your A-z pattern matches more than just letters, it matches ^ and some other symbols. You need to change it to A-Za-z.

```
string allowable3 = "[a-zA-Z0-9 $%&#?+=!]{3}";
Regex regex1 = new Regex("^" + digits4 + allowable3 + "$");
```

Comment: Sorry, will add formatting and reference later,II'm on a mobile.

Comment: The anchors part was the concept I was missing.  The "A-z" is a typo that I probably would have taken more than an hour to see, after which I would have started hitting myself in the head and cursing.  Thanks for both!

Comment: .NET regex shorthand character classes are Unicode aware. If one needs to match ASCII only, `[A-Za-z]` is still the most appropriate solution. It is especially true for digit matching, lots of people are unaware that `\d` matches more than just `[0-9]` in .NET.